# Using replace method javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a problem with the replace method of javascript. I have a string that is:

```
string1 = one|two|three|four;
```

I wanted to replace("|" with ",");

I tried:

```
string1.replace("|", ",");
```

but is replacing only the first occurence. I also tried:

```
string1.replace(/|/g,",");
```

and result was:

```
string1 = "o,n,e,|,t,w,o,|,t,h,r,e,e,";
```

how can i make it the one below?

```
string1 = "one,two,three";
```

Thanks a lot,
tinks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`|` is a special character in regex. You need to escape it with a backslash.

```
string1.replace(/\|/g,",");
```

[**Live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/fYJkH/)

Answer (score 5):

`|` is a special character in regular expressions which makes an or selection between the left and right operands, and you must escape it with a backslash to use it as a literal character.

```
string1.replace(/\|/g,",");

string1 = "one|two|three|four";
"one|two|three|four"
string1.replace(/\|/g, ",");
"one,two,three,four"
```

Answer (score 3):

You didn't escape the pipe character in the regular expression:

```
var string1 = "one|two|three|four";
string1.replace(/\|/g,",")
```

Comment: I look late to the party now... dang researching.

Comment: You need to know this stuff my heart or you'll never be competitive on SO, haha

Comment: I always think I know, but I still have to check to make sure. Probably why I'm still under 1K. Oh well! :)

Comment: Strange though that my answer was just as helpful as the others (if a minute or two behind), but no upvotes at all.

Comment: it's a harsh world haha. But you're well on your way. Here, have an upvote, and good luck for the rest!

Comment: Thanks! It's always nice to run into pleasant people online.